# Automatic update of data in a column based on two others

Tags: mysql

how to add group_aso column automation. Below I have to manually update the database. Can it be done via column virtuality - stored or maybe some trigger?
I would like the group_aso column to be "analyzed" in the event of a change in the data in the REPACK and LABEL columns. I would like to replace manual update with automatic.

```
update MyTable
      set group_aso = 
          case REPACK when 'YES' then 'REPACK' else 'LABEL' end
    where (REPACK = 'YES' and LABEL = 'NO')
       or (REPACK = 'NO' and LABEL = 'YES')
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to implement your query as a *calculated column* possibly?

Comment: I am very beginner in mysql, I am asking for tips or a solution that I will analyze how to do such an implementation myself next time.

Comment: The algorithm is quite simple, so I'd prefer to get this value immediately in the query and not create an additional column.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using a generated column for the task you describe:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE MyTable
  DROP COLUMN group_aso,
  ADD COLUMN group_aso ENUM('LABEL', 'REPACK') 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      CASE repack WHEN 'YES' THEN 'REPACK'
      ELSE 'LABEL' END);

mysql> INSERT INTO mytable (repack, label) VALUES 
  ('YES', 'YES'), 
  ('NO', 'YES'), 
  ('NO', 'NO');

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
| id | repack | label | group_aso |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | YES    | YES   | REPACK    |
|  2 | NO     | YES   | LABEL     |
|  3 | NO     | NO    | LABEL     |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/create-table-generated-columns.html for more information on generated columns in MySQL.